How did Commissioned Officers of the Vietnam-era United States Army become Army Aviation pilots?
I am currently writing a story wherein a character is a UH-1H Huey pilot during the Vietnam War. They are a Commissioned Officer, either through West Point or Officer Candidate School (I am yet to decide which better suits the narrative), and a not insignificant portion of the story concerns their training to fly helicopters before being deployed.
In trying to research how people entered into Army Aviation School during the time (mid to late 1960s), the majority of material concerns Warrant Officer Candidates - these being those who entered exclusively into aviation pathways.
What would the pathway look like for a West Point or OCS graduate who wished to fly helicopters? Would they enter first as a Warrant Officer, or retain their status as a Second Lieutenant? Would they perform greater administrative roles compared to direct WOs?

I don't have any detailed knowledge of US Army Aviation, but it seems obvious that someone who is already commissioned and wants to go to flight school is aiming to become a commander of helicopter units. Is that consistent with the plot and characterisation?

I suspect it worked pretty much as it does now - graduates list their service preferences and the Army goes down the list and tries to fulfill them, with higher ranking cadets getting priority over lower ranking cadets. Graduate in the top 10% and you are likely getting your highest preference.

I know getting an appointment to a service academy period can be quite a process (basically gotta both be worthy and kiss the ass of a senator or House rep somehow) but I suspect you know that part already, and it wasn't exactly the question.

AFAIK, Army Warrant officers are non-commissioned.  Once commissioned, the individual would be ineligible to be a W.O.

In US service, Warrant Officers above the grade of WO1, the entry WO grade, are commissioned warrant officer and are thus "commisioned officers" as opposed to the WO1 who merely holds a warrant.

Commissioned officers of the US Army from any branch can request flight training and, if accepted, go through the commissioned officers flight training program.  The officer's program omits all the how to be a warrant officer - as opposed to an enlisted man - and charm school portions found in the WO flight training program.
Flight training can be either fixed-wing or rotary wing.
Prior to the advent of the helicopter as a major source of transportation most US Army pilots were fixed wing and usually came from the Artillery branch.  Once helicopters became vogue, and the resultant expansion of army aviation, the army decided to go with warrant officers, youngsters entering the service specifically for the flight program or straight from basic training.  A young man's game, but the Army was not interested in having enlisted pilots, ergo, warrant officers.
